# SAS PROC SQL encoding problem for Swedish letters

Tags: encoding, sas, proc

I have a problem of reading the data file includes swedish alphabets (åäö).
I have following code

```
proc sql;
    create table &newFileName9 as
    select * from wd.&sasName (encoding="e143");
quit;
```

and i receive the error

```
ERROR: Module ë ëß€{ê< not found in search paths.
```

Any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi can you please elaborate a bit more? what are the values of `&newFileName9` and `&sasName`?  run this to check the encoding of your session `proc options option=encoding;    
run; `

Comment: The default installation (in US) has three start SAS choices, `SAS 9.4 (English)`, `SAS 9.4 (English with DBCS)` and `SAS 9.4 (Unicode Support)`.  Are you running the Unicode version of SAS ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply needed encoding for both input and output datasets.

`proc sql;
    create table &newFileName9(encoding="ebcdic1143") as
    select * from wd.&sasName (encoding="ebcdic1143");
quit;`

[more info here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/nlsref/63072/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0yzq7l349vrywn1v34gtxx6zqtu.htm)

If won't work, try to set global LOCALE option to Swedish.